# Is the book wrong or me?

Tags: references, error

it's my first question on this forum.

I just purchased [Probability and Statistics - Basic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006WQ9AJI) book from amazon to refresh and learn what I've never learned.  I like the book it explains the subject well.  However, I got a different result on one of the examples.

**Example:**
2 fair dice are rolled.  What is the probability of getting a sum less than 7 or a sum equal to 10?

The books claims that P(A) = 15/36 and P(B) = 1/36. And base on that P(A or B) = 4/9.

I agree on P(A) but I believe that P(B) should be equal to 3/36, including {(4,6), (5,5), (6,4)} rolls.  Therefore, my final result is P(A or B) = 3/6.

Am I missing something or the book got it wrong?

Comment: Two comments. P(A and B)=0, the question asks about P(A or B). In this [link](http://admin.net-texts.com/assetViewer.aspx?dl=no&id=5548) they make the same mistake you mention.

Comment: I already corrected the question per gung note.  It looks like it's the same book.  Thanks for the link.  Now I have an online version too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without bothering to check P(A), you should know that books like this (to include books on pure math, programming, and statistics, as well as probability) *always* have typos.  That's not a remark intended to disparage the authors or editors, etc.  It simply isn't possible to have a book like this without something getting by.  There is no question that there is more than one way to roll 2 fair dice and get a 10.  I would guess that the real typo was to calculate the probability of getting a 12 rather than a 10, but as stated, you're right here.

One other thing, they presumably also meant p(A **or** B).

Comment: It is p(A or B).  I'll correct my questions.  Thanks.